# Adding the value to a property in an object based on a condition

Tags: javascript

Is there any simpler way to achieve this below snippet, I have an object based on the selection of a value i need to add the value to either of one property and make another one as zero.

```
let obj = {
  credit: 0,
  debit: 0,
  userType: formData.userType.value
};

switch (formData.userType.value) {
  case USER_TYPES.NORMAL:
    obj = {
      ...obj,
      credit: formData.amount,
    };
    break;
  case USER_TYPES.GREEDY:
    obj = {
      ...obj,
      debit: formData.amount,
    };
    break;
  default:
    obj = {
      ...obj,
    };
    break;
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: What is the value of `formData.userType.value` for the default case? Is it always the same value? What is that value?

Comment: gimme 2 minutes

Comment: its a dropdown box, so default won't come user needs to select either of one @RobMonhemius

Comment: and here i thought i was gonna be quick :{

Comment: It could be something as simple as `let obj = { credit: formData.userType.value === USER_TYPES.NORMAL && formData.amount || 0, debit: formData.userType.value === USER_TYPES.GREEDY && formData.amount || 0, userType: formData.userType.value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const propMap = { [USER_TYPES.NORMAL]: 'credit', [USER_TYPES.GREEDY]: 'debit'};
if (propMap[formData.userType.value]) {
   obj[propMap[formData.userType.value]] = formData.amount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it directly when you declare and initialize the `obj` variable:

```js
let obj = {
  credit: formData.userType.value === USER_TYPES.NORMAL && formData.amount || 0, 
  debit: formData.userType.value === USER_TYPES.GREEDY && formData.amount || 0, 
  userType: formData.userType.value
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: They don't want the `credit`, `debit` all the time. They want to add that conditionally

Comment: @adiga, the questions says "*I need to add the value to either of one property **and make another one as zero***"

Comment: i think. this will also work, because either debit will have value or credit but at that time the other one credit or debit will be zero

Comment: You're right, they *have* added credit and debit in the original object. I did not see that. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the old `if/else`? `obj.usertype` is also the same as `formData.userType.value`.

```
let obj = {
  credit: 0,
  debit: 0,
  userType: formData.userType.value
};

if( obj.userType === USER_TYPES.NORMAL ) obj.credit = formData.amount;
else if( obj.userType === USER_TYPES.GREEDY ) obj.debit = formData.amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the `switch`, all you need is to create Object `map` to desired `keys`.

Example:

```js
const map = {
    USER_TYPES.NORMAL: 'credit',
    USER_TYPES.GREEDY: 'debit'
}

const obj = {
    credit: 0,
    debit: 0,
    [map[formData.userType.value]]: formData.amount 
}
```